# Reversing the digits of $2^n$ to yield a prime power

Tags: number-theory, recreational-mathematics

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2893768/reversing-digits-of-power-of-2-to-yield-power-of-7) asks about the existence of an $n\in\Bbb N$ such the number obtained reversing de digits of $2^n$ is a power of $7$. The same question with $5$ instead of $7$ was asked by Freeman Dyson, according to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/754211/is-there-a-power-of-2-that-written-backward-is-a-power-of-5). So I asked myself: for which $n\in\Bbb N$ is the number obtained reversing de digits of $2^n$ a prime power? Clearly $n=1,2,3$ work, as do $n=4,5$, since $61$ and $23$ are prime. A computer search up to $n\le 10\,000$ found
$$
1,2,3,4,5,17, 24, 37, 45, 55, 70, 77, 107, 137, 150, 271, 364, 1157, 1656,\\ 2004, 2126, 3033, 3489, 3645, 4336, 6597, 7279
$$
Except for $n=2,3$, the number obtained reversing de digits of $2^n$ is prime (sequence [A057708](http://oeis.org/search?q=4%2C5%2C7%2C10%2C17%2C24%2C37%2C45&sort=&language=english&go=Search)). So, my question is:

> Is there an an $n\in\Bbb N$, $n\ne2,3$, such that the number obtained reversing de
>   digits of $2^n$ is a prime power with exponent at least $2$?

Comment: Do you restrict your attention to base $10$, or are other bases (besides powers of $2$) allowed?

Comment: At this moment, base 10 is my main focus. But of  course other bases and powers are posible.

Comment: How is $2^1=2$ a power of 7?

Comment: No further prime powers upto $n=10^4$, hence a further example would be a miracle , but I do not see a way to rule it out.

Comment: @user25406 2 is a prime power.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre, I was reacting to the first sentence and I quote "...such the number obtained reversing de digits of 2^n is a power of 7."

Comment: I also quote:for which $n\in\Bbb N$ is the number obtained reversing de digits of $2^n$ a prime power?

Answer (score 0):

Let $r$ be the reversal function.
$2^{10} = r(7^4)-r(3^4)$
$6^{3} = r(2^9)+1$
$19^{2} = r(7^3)+r(3^4)$
$54^{2} = r(2^{13})-2$
$252^{2} = r(2^{16})-r(5^2)$
$973^{2} = r(7^6)-r(3^4)$

More interesting is to ask how close one can get, setting up a reverse-digit [ABC conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abc_conjecture) equivalent.