# Example for $(a,b,n,k) \in \mathbb{N}^4$, $r(a^n) = b^k$, where $r$ is the reverse of a number

Tags: number-theory

While writing [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/930179/153012) I got an idea to generalize the problem.

**Question.** Could anybody tell me such $(a,b,n,k) \in \mathbb{N}^4$ $4$-tuple, $a,b,n,k>1$, $a \neq b$, which satisfies the following equality:

$$r(a^n) = b^k,$$

where $r$ denotes the [reverse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/472981/formula-for-reversing-digits-of-positive-integer-n/473074#473074) of a number.

Comment: $r(12^2) = 21^2$ and $r(13^2) = 31^2$

Comment: See also https://oeis.org/A035123 "Roots of 'non-palindromic squares remaining square when written backwards'." 12, 13, 21, 31, 33, 99, 102, 103, 112, 113, 122,.... and the less interesting list at https://oeis.org/A035125, Roots of 'non-palindromic cubes remaining cubic when written backwards', where all 24 entries listed have only zeros and ones for digits.

Answer (score 1):

One interesting example is $r(2201^3)=2201^3$, see https://oeis.org/A002780.

Comment: In this example $a=b$, but thank you anyway.

Comment: It's still interesting. The point is that 2201 doesn't equal its reverse, but its cube does. It's the only known number with that property.