# Expected value of Reversed Addition

Tags: elementary-number-theory

A [recent CodeGolf question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/53216/backwards-long-addition) defines "reverse addition" for two integers $a, b$ as follows: do normal "grade-school" addition, but from left-to-right (with leading zeroes as necessary) instead of right-to-left. As an example, consider 145 and 98, which has a summation setup as follows:

```
 145
+ 98
-----
 243
```

This is usual addition - now we do reverse addition:

```
 145
+ 98
-----
 1341
```

Since 1+0 = 1, we have the first entry is 1. Then we add 4+9 = 13, which has a carry of 1, and so the second entry is 3, the third is 4, and the last is 1 from the previous carry.

I will define the result of reverse addition for $a, b$ is $reverseadd(a, b)$.

My question is: given $a, b$, how does $reverseadd(a, b)$ behave for larger values of $a$ and $b$, and how does it compare to $a+b$ (the original addition)? Given the examples in the linked question, there does not seem to be a correlation, since $reverseadd(22,58)=701$, whereas $reverseadd(73,33) = 7$.

I developed Python 3 code to return the reversed addition of $a, b$ (that may be useful for finding heuristics):

```
def r_add(a, b):
    s_a = str(a)
    s_b = str(b)
    if len(s_a) < len(s_b):
        s_a = s_a.zfill(len(s_b))
    elif len(s_a) > len(s_b):
        s_b = s_b.zfill(len(s_a))
    # now same length
    s_a = s_a[::-1]
    s_b = s_b[::-1]
    return int(str(int(s_a)+int(s_b))[::-1])
```

If you prefer to use another language, you can use some of the answers to the linked question.

**Edit**: after looking at values of $a, b \le 200$, there does seem to be a lot of cool symmetries:
[image]

Comment: "given a,b, what is the *expected value* of reverseadd(a,b)?" ... hmm? If you're given a and b, then there's simply a value - what do you mean by "expected value"?

Comment: @GregMartin Oh I phrased that wrong, I'll edit.

Comment: It appears to me as tho reverse addition is more about reversing numbers before and after adding than it is changing the order in which you add digits. Maybe this post will help in your endeavors. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/323268/formula-to-reverse-digits